# MOOV atom not found - is there a way how to extract the audio from corrupted mp4?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to recover mp4 video file. Having a video would be nice, having an audio is crucial.
I've recorded the fottage with LG v30 which has some kind of HQ audio, therefore normal recovery software is unable to recover it (video was recovered with ease).

That's why I want to try different approach - separate audio from video already from an corrupted file.

but, I'm hitting the "MOOV atom not found" problem, using FFmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i sample.avi -q:a 0 -map a sample.mp3
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: _"I'm trying to recover mp4 video file"_ then shows `ffmpeg -i sample.avi`?? Anyways without MOOV you cannot extract anything. It means you only have the MDAT (which is media data section) and it is all the a/v bytes mixed into one chunk so you won't know which bytes mean what since MOOV has the a/v frame index and size tables.

Comment: Well, I've quite successfully recovered video. So because of "moov", only audio is lost than ?

Comment: @JZK bro, how did you recover it? I'm in a similar situation but with an LG v35 lol. Please share your wisdom, fellow stackoverflow dweller. In my case I REALLY need the video.

Comment: I have sad news ... I couldn't. {{{ I was only able to recover the video with some command line tool on internet, but it seems that audio got lost somewhere. If you can find some solution, it would help me as well, but for now all I can say is, I'm sorry

Comment: @JZK I just need the video, can you please point me to the method you used to recover the video? Just recovering the video is fine for my situation.